Considering Suleiman’s decree in 1537, does the Hebrew of Dan 9:24-27; actually teach a double 70 week prophecy?
I've learned about a second decree of Sultan Suleiman to rebuild Jerusalem, which was engraved in stone in  1537-1541 AD.

An inscription in Arabic from the reign of Suleiman the Magnificent states:

"Has decreed the construction of the wall he who has protected the home of Islam with his might and main and wiped out the tyranny of idols with his power and strength, he whom alone God has enabled to enslave the necks of kings in countries (far and wide) and deservedly acquire the throne of the Caliphate, the Sultan son of the Sultan son of the Sultan son of the Sultan, Suleyman." — quoted from Israel Museum gallery


I found this information in the book “Witnessing the end” by Dr. Christian Widener.
So I began to consider what Dr. Widener put forth.
He said that Daniel 9:24-27 prophesy does not call for an unfulfilled 70th week that still needs to be fulfilled, as is commonly held, but that these verses have a double application to two separate decrees, and while the first 70 weeks set has been fulfilled, — the second set of 70 weeks has not, and, as I understand, we are now currently in the final week of the second set, or we soon will be.

With the information of this new decree as an anchor point. The nuance seems to accurately align with relevant biblical themes,  and with historical, and current geopolitical events.
I would like some feedback,  suggestions, or comments, concerning my translation, if there are any apparent grammar violations, or  any issues  with my conclusion and over all approach to this interpretation?
King James: Dan.9.24.

Seventy weeks are determined upon thy people and upon thy holy city, to finish the transgression, and to make an end of sins, and to make reconciliation for iniquity, and to bring in everlasting righteousness, and to seal up the vision and prophecy, and to anoint the most Holy.

Gesenius' Lexicon suggests, that the meaning of H2852 is 'to cut, to divide', while in translation we see the word 'determined' being used.
In light of the definition given above; below is my translation, using the exact ordering of the Masoretic Text (as given on the Bible tool app).
Dan.9.24:

there are H5921 עַל־ divided H2852 נֶחְתַּךְ seventy H7657 שִׁבְעִים weeks H7620 שָׁבֻעִים; for the holy H6944 קָדְשֶׁךָ city H5892 עִיר (old Jerusalem); and your peoples H5971 עַמְּךָ rebellion הַפֶּשַׁע 6588; by restraining H3607 נֶחְתַּךְ the sin H2304 חַטָּאת ( 2 Thes. 2.6-7); and are marked out H2856 for the coming h935 punishment H5771, which is for purging H3722 cp. Dan.12.10).

And here is my first question: is it grammatically right to read that verse as such?

Here we have a seeming intended thought play, between a “separate” set of 70 weeks (70/70). Which is slightly veiled within the text (as will be shown below); and with a divided 70 weeks, which is what one would naturally conclude, in simply reading the “62” in the preceding passages (7+62×1).
The vision H2377, and its sealing up H2856 (Dan.12.4) are concerned with the age H5769 of righteousness H6664; and is when the holy H6944 of holies, H6944 will be anointed H4886 (Ez. 43-48).
This prophecy H530 (Dan.9.25) to some H4480 will be made understood H7919, and known H3045; that from the building H7919, and restoration H7725 from the word H1697, that went forth
H4161 for a ruler H5057, who is to be anointed H4899 for Jerusalem H3389; there shall be the weeks H7620:
Here we are giving the two starting points, of the two sets of 70 weeks. The first 70 starts from the building in 459 bc, and the second  from the restoration of the wall, 1541.B.C.
“the ruler, anointed” is Cyrus whom God calls His anointed (Isa.45.1); and also applies to Suleman.
Seventy H7651 (cp. Gen.4.24), seven H7620 (cp.Ez.45.21), then they shall build H1129;
seventy Seven years from the decree of Cyrus 536 B.C., ends at 459 B.C., and is when the building of the city began.
The “sealing up” of the vision corresponds with the “ the this prophecy” that will be made understood and known, cp. Dan. 12.9-10; and
should be read in verse 25;
And it shall be returned at H7725 the second H8147 (H8147 is rendered “second “ in Dan.2.1), sixty H8346; and anguished H6695, and diligence H2742 will be in their streets H7339 in those times H6296.
From the completion of Suleiman’s building of the wall, in 1541 A.D (+ 490 = 2031 A.D); unto “the second 60th week”, is 1961-68; and is when Jerusalem, the old city; the original Jerusalem, referred today as “east” Jerusalem; was returned under Jewish control, after the 6 day war 1967, giving confirmation that Suleiman’s restoration, is the starting point, and what is meant by the meaning of a divide between the building starting point, and the restoration as a starting point.
Dan. 9.26: Two H8147 and sixty H8346 weeks H7620 after H310; none לוֹ ( not numbered in the Heb.), but not being for H369 Messiah H4899, will be cut off H3722 (Acts.3.23).
Here the 62 weeks, after the restoration of the sanctuary is implying the arrival of the Messiah.
For there will be corruption/ destruction H7843 for the holy H6924 city H5892 (the destruction of the Roman siege, Lk.21.20-24; A.D., 69-70 A.D.). (And a double application to the Dome of the rock, which says “God has no Son”.
And shall come H935 of the ruler H5057 the people H5971 with a flood H7858;
(i.e., Oct.7, 2023; Al-Aqsa “Flood” fullfilment, or first aspect of fullfilment; the  Hamas-led attack; “the people” of Saladin, i.e., the ottoman kingdom, i.e., Islamic jihad).
(Seen on stellarium, on Oct.7th, astroid named "child" comes out of Virgo, possible partial, or full fulfillment of Rev.12.1-13; cp. Isa.26.17-21).
Rev.12:2-5 And she being with child cried, travailing in birth, and pained to be delivered.And there appeared another wonder in heaven; and behold a great red dragon, having seven heads and ten horns, and seven crowns upon his heads.And she brought forth a man child, who was to rule all nations with a rod of iron: and her child was caught up unto God, and to his throne.
Isaiah 26:17 Like as a woman with child, that draweth near the time of her delivery, is in pain, and crieth out in her pangs; so have we been in thy sight, O LORD.
Isaiah 26:19 Thy dead men shall live, together with my dead body shall they arise. Awake and sing, ye that dwell in dust: for thy dew is as the dew of herbs, and the earth shall cast out the dead.
Isaiah 26:20 Come, my people, enter thou into thy chambers, and shut thy doors about thee: hide thyself as it were for a little moment, until the indignation be overpast.
And at the end H7093, desolation H8074 is determined H2782, for the battle H4421 at the end 7093 of the week. 7620
Dan.9.27: And many of the H7727 covenant H1285 He shall cause to prevail H1396 for the week H7620, and a half H2677 of one H259 (Zech.10.6,12); and upon H5921 an offering H4503 of sacrifice H2077; He shall bring to an end H7673 abominations H8251; upon wings H3671, even intill H5704 the one who shall make desolate H8074, pours out that H5413 which is decreed H2782 for the consummation H3617 on it HH5921
The “week”; and the half of the following one, is implying when the elect will be saved out of the time of persecution (i.e., the time of tribulation) soon after it begins (Dan.12.1-3; Mt.24. 29-31; 2 Thes. 4. 15-17 ). Which will be around the middle period of the final week.
When the sufferings of Christ are filled up by His body (cp. Col.1.25); it is by this sacrificial service that God will cause the abominations end. This implies that it is by their sufferings, which must be fulfilled, before God’s wrath comes upon the world:
Rev 6:10  “And they cried with a loud voice, saying, How long, O Lord, holy and true, dost thou not judge and avenge our blood on them that dwell on the earth?  v11  And white robes were given unto every one of them; and it was said unto them, that they should rest yet for a little season, until their fellow servants also and their brethren, that should be killed as they were, should be fulfilled.
“Upon an offering of sacrifice”, is when the body is caught up to God, soon after the tribulation begins; their sacrificial service, will result in God bringing to a end abomination, by the coming  wrath of the day of the LORD (cp. Rev 12.10).
They will be saved out of the tribulation unto God, as an offering of sacrifice, unto Himself for the reconciliation of the cosmos, back under the dominion of His image  Col.1.15-22, 24; Dan12.1-3; Mt.24.21-22, 29-30; Eph.1.4; 18; 2.6-10; 5. 26-27; Rev.14.7).
At this time the woman (i.e. the persevered of Israel) will be persevered, being brought on “wings” to the wilderness, intill the final return of Christ, when he will desolate the abomination.
When we turn to related passages in Daniel, we find the word "sacrifice" is not in the original; it only takes place in 9.27; and in all these other scriptures (Daniel 8:11-13; 11:31; 12:11); it was attempted by the translators to alline these verses, with Antiochus Epiphanies, by injecting the word "sacrifice" to the English translation. (Which in my opinion really throws us of from the authors intended meaning).
Here is an example: Dan.12.11 "And shall understand the wise continually H8548; that shall be removed H5493 (cp. Gen. 8.13) from the time H6265 of the desolation H8074 of abomination H825, that shall be given over H5414 1290 days (Cp. Rev.12.1-15).
So the wise will be removed; but the unwise are not, but they will be preserved in the wilderness, being carried on wings (Rev.12. 3-7, 14; Dan.12.10; Mt. 25.2).Then at the end of this final week, the battle of Armageddon will take place.
In summary, (which diferers from Dr. Widener); the first set of 70 weeks begin from the building of city in BC 459 (which was 77 yrs after the decreed of Cyrus, who was God’s anointed (Isa.45.1); and culminate with the first coming of the Messiah, His ministry to Israel,  and ending the final week at His crucifixion; which resulted in the cutting off of the people, that are against Him, and the destruction of the holy city (Acts. 3.23; Rom. 11). Being that, they did not recognize the time of visitation (AD 70, Lk.19.42-44).
The second set of 70 weeks concern the return of old Jerusalem back under Jewish control; and a prevailing of the people of the covenant (that do not rebel, ie the departure); who during the time of anguish (i.e. the tribulation); are purified, and will turn to God in righteousness (Dan.12. 1, 10).
The vision and the prophecy culminate with the final return of Christ Jesus; who will destroy the beast kingdom, and establish His Kingdom upon the earth; bringing desolation to the abomination (Dan.2.44-45; 7:13-14, 27; cp. Acts.1.6)
So what yall think? There are a lot of links, that make me believe this is how the N.T. writers read these verses.

May I ask how the question might differ if taking the Bible itself as the final authority?

This text involves geopolitical events,  so if we don't look at history, it opposes what the Prophecy says. But my question is focused on the translation.

This reads more like a statement and "mark my homework" than a real question.

69 weeks (483 years) of that prophecy paused when Christ entered Jerusalem when He was proclaimed to be Israel's Messiah. The final 7 prophetic years of Israel (the tribulation) will ensue upon the completion of this current age of God's grace (Eph 3:2)...when the fulness of the Gentile body of believers, the church, the body of Christ, will have come in (Rom 11:25).

Well ant that what hermeneutics is, I am putting forth my conclusion,  through the information I provided, and my question is to a community of people who have a wider range of knowledge concerning herbrew grammar.

tl;dr I can't decipher any particular question about any particular text. This tells about a journey with many texts in studying a topic. This has Bible verses and manuscript references, but doesn't quote any of them. How about quoting the main Bible verse this is about, even in Hebrew/Aramaic, then quote other texts to ask how they relate to the Bible passage? It needs a concise passage and a concise question, then an elaboration could follow it if it is a lot shorter (a lot that can be cut out). Once that is done, click "Flag" and ask a mod for re-open, and we'll look at it.

Don't see any problems,  I am asking if my translation is correct,  with the information about a decree to rebuild Jerusalem,  and translated the text listed, and asked if there are grammatical errors. So don't see an issue, sounds like maybe you disagree with the information

I think this is a Jesuit ran site

How many times have I asked a question concerning a translation,  I put forth ? Dottard is quick to correct it ( not this time though), seems strange, I am asking a clear question,  if Dan.9 24-37, teaches two sets of seventy weeks. And gave the reasons for my understanding of the nuance.  It's not thst hard to understand my question?

I don't know of any Jesuits on the site, but that is an interesting thought. Re-opening this would be great. We want that. But, it needs to be understandable first. The big issue here is that it needs to be readable; right now, it looks like a big wall of text with many Bible verses, and no clear, single, specific question. That's only about style. We don't want a great question closed just because of style, but style matters. Here are some suggestions...

To check your translation, put your entire translation in a block quote. Above the block quote, put your source reference —whether numbers from a museum, Bible verses, name for the specific source text/manuscript. Also, if you can, find a web address/URL online and make your source reference a hyperlink to that web address/URL. Avoid listing too many other Bible verses because we want to focus on one verse, but if you want to contrast Bible verses against your translation to check, use bullet points and/or use small text in a block quote of each. This makes it understandable.

Also, make sure that your text is among the texts we examine on this site. If you have an outside text—but it could be helpful to provide background/historical context for the texts which we do examine here, then explain that connection clearly and briefly.

I don't know how to do it, but the text that I referenced,  are all related, to themes that must be understood to understand the authors intention, whithout that, there will not be enough evidence to prove if my rendering,  or any is accurate.

I see that you've been working hard on this one - essentially, as others have said, there are still various issues. It's not readable (wall of text), it's self-answering (Answer included in the Q), and is fairly eisegetical - cramming a load of history and later texts into the verse, which could end up influencing it to say something that may not naturally arise from the passage in its own context.

No.  Pay careful attention to vs. 26:

24 `Seventy weeks are determined for thy people, and for thy holy city, to shut up the transgression, and to seal up sins, and to cover iniquity, and to bring in righteousness age-during, and to seal up vision and prophet, and to anoint the holy of holies.


25 And thou dost know, and dost consider wisely, from the going forth of the word to restore and to build Jerusalem till Messiah the Leader [is] seven weeks, and sixty and two weeks: the broad place hath been built again, and the rampart, even in the distress of the times.


26 And after the sixty and two weeks, cut off is Messiah, and the city and the holy place are not his, the Leader who hath come doth destroy the people; and its end [is] with a flood, and till the end [is] war, determined [are] desolations.


27 And he hath strengthened a covenant with many -- one week, and [in] the midst of the week he causeth sacrifice and present to cease, and by the wing of abominations he is making desolate, even till the consummation, and that which is determined is poured on the desolate one.'  (Dan. 9:25-27, YLT)

When was the Messiah cut off?  When was He crucified?  Approx. AD 30-31 in the first century AD.  Now look at vs. 25.  This prophecy is addressed to Daniel's people, and Daniel's holy city, ie. the Jews and Jerusalem.  The prophecy concerns only the desolations (destruction) of the Jews and their city Jerusalem during the time when the Messiah was cut off in the middle of the 70th week.
From my post The Seventy Weeks of Daniel Chap. 9 (here):
"First, notice that Gabriel is speaking to Daniel, and the subject is Daniel’s people…“thy people”, the Israelites, and the holy city….Jerusalem!   Daniel’s people were not the Romans, or the Greeks, or the Edomites, or the Ammonites.   They were the Jews.   Daniel earnestly wanted to know what was going to happen to his people.  The entire prophecy of the seventy weeks is clearly stated in the first sentence to be about the Jews and their city, Jerusalem.
If you are attempting to apply this prophesy to some other nation, or to some future as yet unknown people of Daniel you are gravely mistaken!  Nor, can it about the current Zionist political dream creation of “Eretz Yisrael”, the so called holy land, for reasons I will explain further on.
Next, let’s notice that Daniel 9 occurs in the first year of Darius’ reign (c.9:v.1).  Darius rose to power after Cyrus’ reign ended in the second empire of the dream of Daniel 2, that is the Mede-Persian empire.   And, then let’s notice that the seventy weeks begin “from the going forth of the word to restore and rebuild Jerusalem.”
So, the 70 weeks of the prophesy that Gabriel speaks to Daniel in chapter 9 begins some time after Cyrus’ decree was proclaimed for the return of the Jews to Jerusalem.  However, we cannot start counting from Cyrus’ decree because the rebuilding of Jerusalem was not accomplished immediately.  Those that returned to Jerusalem with Joshua the High Priest and Zerubbabel were prevented from rebuilding.
Ezra chap. 3 records the building of the altar, and the sacrifices of the seventh month (Tishri) had begun, but the temple had not yet been “founded”.   The Israelites were frustrated in their attempts to rebuild by the surrounding adversaries through all the days of the reign of Cyrus until the reign of Darius. (Ezra 4)
By the time the adversaries in Samaria and surrounding cities sent a letter of accusation against the Israelites to Artaxerxes, king of Babylon, only the walls and the foundation of Jerusalem had been completed. (Ezra 4:12)   Artaxerxes authorized the halt of the building pending a further decree from him for the restoration to continue. (Ezra 4:21-23)
In the second year of Darius’ reign, the Jews appealed to Darius for relief and permission to continue the building. (Ezra c. 5)   After review of the records of the treasury, Darius issued a decree that not only allowed the Jews to continue, but funded the rebuilding from the taxes owed the king from the accusers in Samaria and beyond the river. (Ezra 6).   This was the decree that was the going forth of the word which Gabriel measured to Daniel as the start of the seventy weeks.  This decree was issued in the second year of the reign of Darius. (Ezra 3:24)  A similar decree was given Nehemiah by Artaxerxes in the 20th year of his rule. (Neh. 2)
We must recognize that the history we read of events prior to the birth of Christ is recorded in years of the reigns of kings.  That makes it very difficult to get an accurate number of years if any one historian has recorded a reign or event incorrectly.   And, as many of the records we have are in cuneiform where scribes could easily have added an extra “wedge” mark by mistake, no accounting of years or time can truly be determined accurately from human records.   Human error builds upon human error, and it becomes impossible to calculate an absolute starting point.
We need to also notice that our current calendar is off by approximately three years.  I believe the best record is obtained by counting backward from A.D. 70 at the destruction of Jerusalem, a known and verifiable date.
We then subtract 40 years for the probate of the will of the testator (Christ), which 40 years is the anti-type of the 40 years of the exodus wilderness, and we reach the cross at 30 A.D.   The cross of Christ, the release from bondage and slavery of sin, the Passover lamb, was the anti-type of the release from bondage and slavery out of Egypt at the last plague, the first Passover.  (See recommending reading link #4 below this post.)
We know that Jesus’ earthly ministry was 3.5 years (3.5*354 lunar days, or 1239 days on the Hebrew calendar), and that He was cut off in the midst of the 70th week (Dan. 9:26), the week after the 69th week.   Subtracting 3-1/2 years (3.39 solar years) from A.D. 30, we get A.D. 26 – A.D. 27 for His baptism by John in the river Jordan at the age of 30.
We must also then ask was He 30 lunar years old by the Hebrew calendar, or 30 solar years old?  I think we must calculate 30 lunar years of age to be consistent, and add the 10 months the Hebrews added to their calendar every third year (30 years divided by three is 10).  Jesus would have been 29 years and 10 months old based upon conversion to a solar calendar.  Luke 3:23, “And Jesus…began to be about thirty years of age…:”
Continuing then, we subtract 29.8 years of His age from time line of 26-27 A.D., and we get his birth in approx. 3 B.C.  Is this even important in the whole scheme of God’s plan?
The seventy weeks, which are seventy years of seven….. do we begin counting from the second year of Darius’ reign, or the 20th year from Artaxerxes’ reign for the going forth of the commandment to rebuild?  And, are we counting to Jesus’ birth, or to His baptism?  The prophesy says “to Messiah” (Young’s), or “unto the Messiah” (KJV)
Some people count to the birth of Christ.  Others count to his baptism, as the word Messiah means the anointed.  Christ was anointed at His baptism by John.  But, I believe an argument can be made that He was also anointed at His birth.
One guess for a starting point is Nehemiah’s work to restore Jerusalem at the decree of Artaxerxes which some historians date from 454 BC.  Add 483 years (62 weeks) equals = 29 A.D.  This is somewhat close to the quick calculation we did above for the date of Jesus’ baptism, and the beginning of His 3-1/2 year ministry.  This calculation would make the cutting off of the Messiah in the midst of the seventieth week 3-1/2 years later approx. 32 – 33 A.D.
We can get close, but human records are problematic, and this can only be considered a contrivance.   Here is another record.
Africanus’ calculation:
“If, for instance, we begin counting the seventy weeks from Cyrus and the first Mission, the period will be too long by more than a century, if from (b) the day the angel prophesied to Daniel still longer, and longer still if we start from the beginning of the Captivity. For we find the length of the Persian Empire to be 230 years, and of the Macedonian 300, and from then to the sixteenth year of Tiberius Caesar 60 years. And from Artaxerxes to the time of Christ seventy weeks are (c) completed according to Jewish reckoning. For from Nehemiah, who was sent by Artaxerxes to rebuild Jerusalem, in the one hundred and fifteenth year of the Persian Empire, and in the twentieth year of Artaxerxes, and in the fourth year of the eighty-third Olympiad up to that date, which was the second year of the two hundred and second Olympiad, and the sixteenth year of the reign of Tiberius Caesar, there are 475 years, or 490 according to Hebrew reckoning. For they reckon years by the course of the moon, I ought to (d) tell you, counting 354 days, while the course of the sun is 365 ¼ days, twelve lunar revolutions, being exceeded by one solar by 11¼ days. Therefore the Greeks and the Jews add three intercalary months to every eighth year. For eight times 11¼ days makes three months. So then 465 years, in eight-year cycles, makes fifty-nine years and three months. Since adding the three intercalary months every eighth year, we have a few days short of fifteen years. And these added (391) to the 475 years complete the seventy weeks.”  (Fifth Book of his Chronography, Quoted in Demonstratio Evangelica (Proof of the Gospel) ;  BOOK VIII)
The entire struggle trying to pinpoint the starting date of the 70 weeks of Daniel c.9 has been going on for centuries, and I believe it to be not only futile, but unnecessary.
It is more accurate to rely upon God’s word as the scriptures have been proven to be true time and again.  We know we can count on what the Holy Spirit has recorded, instead of trying to struggle with the imperfect records of man.  So, let’s examine what the scriptures actually say.
We know that the Messiah was going to be cut off in the midst of the week after the 69th week of Dan. 9 (v25-26).   So, the midst of the 70th week, which immediately followed the 69th week as logic demands, was somewhere between 30 and 33 A.D when He was crucified.   Close enough.   The end of the prophesies of Daniel concern the first century A.D., the crucifixion of Christ, and therefore the destruction of Jerusalem.  The time period is pin pointed very well by the cutting off of the Messiah which we know occurred at the cross in the first century A.D.   We do not have to look any further.
Dan 12:6-7, “6 And one said to the man clothed in linen, which was upon the waters of the river, How long shall it be to the end of these wonders? 7 And I heard the man clothed in linen, which was upon the waters of the river, when he held up his right hand and his left hand unto heaven, and sware by him that liveth for ever that it shall be for a time, times, and an half; and when he shall have accomplished to scatter the power of the holy people, all these things shall be finished.” (KJV)
Dan. 12:11, “ And from the time that the daily sacrifice shall be taken away, and the abomination that maketh desolate set up, there shall be a thousand two hundred and ninety days.”
The abomination of desolation was the Roman army, and they caused sacrifices to the Roman Caesars (gods) to be carried out in the temple in Jerusalem in A.D. 66-67.
Matt. 24:15, “When ye therefore shall see the abomination of desolation, spoken of by Daniel the prophet, stand in the holy place, (whoso readeth, let him understand:)”
Luke 21:20, “And when ye shall see Jerusalem compassed with armies, then know that the desolation thereof is nigh.”
We know that in Matt. 24:2, Jesus told the disciples that the temple was going to be torn down, and that in v. 3 the disciples asked Him when “shall these things be“.  They were shocked at His statement about the destruction of the temple, and their question was immediately concerned with its destruction.   Jesus’ answer throughout all of c.24 concerns that time period of the destruction of the temple and the city of Jerusalem, which we know occurred in A.D. 70.
So, the abomination of desolation of Matt. 24:15, which ties to Dan. 12:11, is confirmed by Luke 21:20…. that the abomination of desolation was the Roman army which surrounded and destroyed Jerusalem and the temple in A.D. 70, and is the same 3-1/2 years (“time, times, and an half”) of Dan. 12 v7, and answers Daniel’s question of when the end would be.
Dan. 12, v7 states that the end of these wonders would be finished when the power of the holy people (Jews) shall have been scattered.
Rev. 11:2, “ But the court which is without the temple leave out, and measure it not; for it is given unto the Gentiles: and the holy city shall they tread under foot forty and two months.“
Three and a half years, or 42 months, or 1260 days, or a time, times, and an half…. from A.D. 67 to the fall of Jerusalem and the destruction of the temple in A.D. 70. the Roman army put an end to national Israel.
God’s chosen people, the Israelites, had been the holy people of God, until they rejected and crucified the Messiah.   Those who were not caught within the city at the destruction of Jerusalem in A.D. 70 were scattered throughout the nations after the destruction.   With the destruction of the temple, all of the genealogical records were gone.  The Jews could no longer prove the Levitical line of the priesthood.   The empty sacrificial offerings that had been continued after Christ’s death ceased.
This was the end of national Israel which God had allowed to be restored upon Cyrus’ decree approx 539 B.C for the sole purpose of the coming of the Messiah.  And, in spite of the contrived “State” of Israel that men recently conspired to establish in 1948, the people who live there today are not national Israel, and are not God’s chosen people.  They cannot prove any lineage to the twelve tribes of Jacob, nor can they put into office any proven Levitical priest.  The Israelites are still scattered to this day throughout all the nations of the world!
A.D. 70 was the end of the prophecies Gabriel showed to Daniel.  Therefore, all of the prophesies of Daniel were events that transpired no later than A.D. 70.  Anyone that tries to span a 2,000 year break in these prophecies does not understand the intent of the prophecy......"
The prophecy from Dan. 9 did not concern any other nation than that of the old Judea and the old city of Jerusalem during the 1st century AD.  Read the full post at the link cited above.
See also Daniel and the End Times at my blog ShreddingTheVeil.org.

Luke 21:27 would have then occurred and Israel's "kingdom of heaven" would have then been delivered.  Israel's prophets did not see the 2,000 (or more) year span that was "kept secret since the world began" (Rom 16:25)...until revealed to Paul.  You are correct that the intent of the prophecy is for Israel and there is no "Israel" today.  We are all equal in God's eyes until His body, the church, has been filled with believers (and caught up in the clouds). This "mystery" church was never before mentioned until revealed to Paul, and is not the same church as Peter's remnant of believing Jews.

@MarkVestal, disagree.  The "church" that began on the day of Pentecost has been on-going ever since AD 30-31.  It has no end.  The mystery was always that YHVH would bring in the gentiles / nations into the promise & make both one in Yeshua's passover / forgivness.  The first catching up into the clouds happened after the temple was destroyed as Jesus promised in Matt. 25 when all those held in Hades were separated out & the righteous taken to heaven.  All who die in the Lord ever since then are taken up into the clouds & into heaven one by one.  It is an on-going process.  See posts:....

Hades is No More: https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/08/25/hades-is-no-more/     and   Testing The Spirits - Part III: Daniel's Lot:  https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/02/12/testing-the-spirits-part-iii-daniels-lot/

Matthew 25 is referencing Christ's millennial reign on earth... yet to occur. Matt 25:31-34 "When the Son of man shall come in his glory, and all the holy angels with him, then shall he sit upon the throne of his glory:
32 And before him shall be gathered all nations: and he shall separate them one from another, as a shepherd divideth his sheep from the goats:
33 And he shall set the sheep on his right hand, but the goats on the left.
34 Then shall the King say unto them on his right hand, Come, ye blessed of my Father, inherit the kingdom prepared for you from the foundation of the world:"

Mark, you r spouting dispensational dogma, which is not according to scripture.  That false view has been around since the mid-1800's & from a twisted perspective.  There is no reign of Christ on earth.  He reigns in heaven at the right hand of the Father now.  His throne of glory is in heaven.  Look at Rev. 20:4 carefully.  Where were the souls of those beheaded?  They were dead, so they were not on earth.  The reign with Christ in heaven.  Pls read:  https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/03/23/the-signs-of-revelation-part-vi-the-judgment-day-chapter-20/

No. Paul is who literally mentions "dispensations"...not me (Eph 3:2, Eph 1:10, Col 1:25, 1 Cor 9:17).  Also, Christ will literally reign on earth. Two angels said that: Acts 1:11 "And while they looked stedfastly toward heaven as he went up, behold, two men stood by them in white apparel; 11 Which also said, Ye men of Galilee, why stand ye gazing up into heaven? this same Jesus, which is taken up from you into heaven, shall so come in like manner as ye have seen him go into heaven." Peter said this is when Israel's "times of refreshing shall come from the presence of the Lord" (Acts 3:19).

Going in the clouds... coming in the clouds... metaphors.. judgment language.  He came back in judgment against those who crucified Him, Rev. 1:7 in the destruction of Jerusalem & that temple in AD 70.  It was not a prophecy of a 1,000 yr literal reign on earth.

Armageddon literally occurs at some point after Christ's literal reign on earth, after Satan has been "loosed a little season" (Rev 20:3) to "deceive the nations" (Rev 20:8). Peter and the eleven will rule with Christ "judging the twelve tribes of Israel" during this reign (Matt 19:28, Luke 22:30). At some point after Armageddon, earthly Israel and the heavenly body of Christ (the church) will come together as one. Eph 1:10 "That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:"

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@gina You mention in your conclusion; "Therefore, all of the prophesies of Daniel were events that transpired no later than A.D. 70."  Did you mean to include the entire book of Daniel or exclusively Daniel 9?

The prophecy begun in Dan. 9 is explained further thru chap. 10 -12,  The "end of days" of Dan. 12:13 is specifically the end of the 490 years Gabriel specified in Dan. 9:24.  It does not speak of the end of all time, but the end of the days marked for the desolation of Jerusalem.  See the posts: https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/01/24/testing-the-spirits-part-ii-the-end/  and  https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/02/12/testing-the-spirits-part-iii-daniels-lot/

The Roman Empire rebuilt Jerusalem after the Bar Kokhba revolt. Rebuilt the Temple Mount into an alter for Jupiter. 130sAD. Jews and Jewish Christians were banned from entering Jerusalem for hundreds of years. That is the “diaspora” James 1 speaks of.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_bar_Kokhba
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aelia_Capitolina
Maccabean Revolt: 167BC
Council of Nicaea: 325AD
-167+490=323AD:
70 weeks after 323AD was the Council of Nicaea. The seventy sevens and seventy weeks occurs in years between the Maccabean Revolt and the Council of Nicaea.
Jewish Roman Wars: 66AD to 136AD:
Bar Kokhba Revolt ends 136AD.
The seventy years occurs between the Jewish Roman Wars and end of Bar Kokhba revolt.

Doesn't seem to fit the prophecy,  can you make it match the timeline in scripture?

Sure, the time frame between the Jewish Roman Wars beginning 66AD and the Bar Kohkba revolt ending in 136AD. 70 years

We are going to need a little more outline that that.

I think 70 years time span is good enough. Life goes on.

Well if that sits good with you that's fine,  but I am asking the question and your answer is none satisfactory. Just saying 70 and throwing dates out there ant gonna fit with the text. English or Hebrew,  your gonna have to exposit the text to your dates, if you know what I mean.

Jerusalem is constantly in state of rebuilding like all cities worldwide.

Revelations doesn’t contain the phrase seventy sevens. So it’s speculated that Daniel 9 was written after the book of Revelations. There’s two names of interest: Theodotion the Jewish scholar, and St Jerome might be the two editors of Daniel 9.  St Jerome mentions how much influence Theodotion’s version of Daniel had impact on the church. It was not exactly the original LXX version. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodotion

The 1000 years of Revelations 20 was the time span from King David 885BC to the Kitos War 115AD.  All the Jews of the diaspora revolted into an apocalypse against the Roman Empire once again. I don’t consider these texts to be truly prophetic. It’s a history book cunningly written as though it was prophecy.

I can't except that the 1000 year kingdom has already come, and I believe the word, there are three sets of Sevens in Rev as a major outline,  along with Daniels prayer for three weeks, could have reference to some aspect of the birth pains period

There’s always a messiah somewhere at anytime. That’s a general overview of Rabbinic Judaism theology on the messiah. There exists a messiah within every generation.

You can see the phenomenon occur right now. Many people of the USA look upon the President to be a messiah. The state of Israel looks upon the support of the USA military to be a messiah.  All nations ask of other nations  for military support, and financial support. That’s the phenomenon of a messiah.

Does the way the years were reckoned factor into this at all? There were differences between the Babylonians, Greeks and Romans which complicate accuracy. I'm interested in hearing the salient question that can be pulled from what looks like pretty good research. You have to call facts what they are and acknowledge the political ideology of Zionism that's here for confusion also. As far as the dispersion being referenced by James as the one after BK... I'm of the opinion that its the one prophesied in Genesis 15:13 and Acts 7:6 which the US Congress acknowledged the anniversary of in 2019.
